# How to separate text using substring

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering how can I separate a column containing the following:

```
 BURGER, Petrus (CHV 494081)
```

Into 3 columns:

```
 FirstName, LastName, ID
```

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for the expression for regexp_matches. I believed I should have clarify the question in greater details. What I am trying to achieve is to split information in 1 column into 3 columns. I made attempted in Split_part function but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a[2] AS FirstName,
  a[1] AS LastName,
  a[3] AS ID
FROM (
  SELECT regexp_matches(column_name, '(.+), (.+) \((.+)\)')
  FROM table_name
) t(a)
```