# How do you insert part of an exsisting column record into a new table in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm in the process of formatting a database and have found a column I'd like to format. It has 3 types of information for every record in the column. For example, a record in my history column shows as **(American, born Estonia. 19011974)**. What I want to do is put this data into new individual columns to make them atomic. I want to extract data such as 'American' into a country column, 'Estonia' into a born column and '1901' into a born column and '1974' into a death column.  **UPDATE:** However, some of the columns hold nullls, for example, another record in the same column might be **(German, 19242004)**, so a normal regular expression wouldn't work for all data would it? Any help is appreciated!

What PostgreSQL statements would I use to obtain specific parts of this data from the individual records? I understand it would be insert and have already came up with:

```
INSERT INTO historian (id,url)
SELECT  object_id, url FROM maintable;
```

that statement allowed me to get those values into new columns, but those were atomic already so I could easily transition them. Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Sounds very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516102/how-to-separate-text-using-substring/35518121#35518121)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll try messing around with it!